# how to read data from memory on microblaze using sdk

Tags: fpga, microblaze, xilinx-edk

I use an atlyse spartan-6 xc6slx45 and I try to do a C code on sdk which permit to read data from a memory of microblaze then do a multiplication of two matrix.I found many tutorials which make the initialisation of the two input matrixes on the C code.Can any one have an idea or a tutorial how to configure the code to read the data input from the memory of the microblaze?

Comment: Why do you need any tutorial on mcroblaze when this is a common C programming question? You access your memory like any other standard C program on a micro controller, nothing special here.

Comment: the data input should be read from the hyperterminal which is connected to the board,do you know to do that?

Comment: Do you know how to program in C? Read from a terminal and save it to an array, nothing FPGA or Microblaze specific here!